# Running total of a calculated item in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need the running sum of the following in a query in sqlite. 
Sum(of a few items)-Sum(of a few items) As rn
E.g.:
``accno         qtydel       qtyrec    rn     rnt    001                    5                1         4       4      001                    2                0         6     10     001                    5                3         8      18   004                    6                3         9        9    004                    1                2         8       17

Comment: Please clarify the requirements in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines. Show both the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the SQLite [tutorial on window frames](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-window-frame/) ...

Assuming the two columns are labeled a and b in table t:

```
SELECT 
    a,
    b,
    SUM(a) OVER (
        ORDER BY rowid
    ) RunningTotalA,
        SUM(b) OVER (
        ORDER BY rowid
    ) RunningTotalB
FROM t;
```

Output, with headers:

```
a|b|RunningTotalA|RunningTotalB
8|8|8|8
2|10|10|18
3|13|13|31
```

Comment: Sum(Aa+bb+cc)-Sum(dd+ee+ff)+Coalesce(bf,0);AS Rt,     this is already a caculated value. I want the running sum of Rt order by accno

Comment: Acc1 qtyd qtyr  rt  runntotal                                   2          8      4      4      4                                        2          3       0     7      11                                         2          4       2     9      20                                     3          5      1      5        4                                3          4      2      7       11

Comment: Using version 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

If using Sqlite 3.25 or newer, window functions make this trivial:

```
sqlite> WITH mytable(id, n) AS (VALUES (1,8), (2,2), (3,3))
   ...> SELECT n, sum(n) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rnt FROM mytable ORDER BY id;
n           rnt
----------  ----------
8           8
2           10
3           13
```